# Why doesn't the Media Browser use thumbnail sized images?

Tags: admin, post-thumbnails, media, bug

The folks updating our site oft complained about the media browser being very slow, so I went to have a look.

And, on the first load of the page, and when doing a search within the media browser, its taking a while to download each of the image previews, even longer than it should on our shonky office broadband.

So, I inspected the source of the page, and it became clear. Each image thumbnail is actually linking to the full size image, and resizing it in HTML, see:

[image]

Is this an issue anyone's aware of? Is there a workaround? I'd presume there should be a *built in* thumbnail type for that purpose.

Comment: Mabye my [workaround here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177571/26350) can help you?

Comment: This isn't happening on my site

Comment: It should use the `medium` size - either you've disabled this size, or the image was too large to resize in the first place (not enough memory).

Comment: @birgire your workaround worked perfectly to sort this out, it now uses a custom image size in replacement of the `medium` size.

Comment: @gravy glad to hear it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, my theme was missing the system default `medium` image size.

Applying @birgire's workaround to make the system use a custom size did the trick.